# Why does TLS needs to have a separate key for client and server

Tags: tls

TLS protocol presented [The First Few Milliseconds of an HTTPS Connection](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html), there are two cipher keys Cb and Cs. One key is used only by the client, and the other is used only by the server. Likewise, there are two integrity keys Ib and Is. 
My question is why do we need two set of key, why don't we just simply share one cipher key C and one integrity key I.